# Проблема со звуком плеера

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, аудио, qmediaplayer

Создал простой плеер по уроку, все работает хорошо, только звук будто захлебывается.

Может ли быть ошибка в коде?

Код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtMultimedia

class AudioPlayer(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent, flags = QtCore.Qt.Window | QtCore.Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)

        self.setWindowTitle("Audio Player")

        self.mplPlayer = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.mplPlayer.setVolume(50)
        self.mplPlayer.mediaStatusChanged.connect(self.init_player)
        self.mplPlayer.stateChanged.connect(self.set_player_state)

        vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        button_open = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Open file")
        button_open.clicked.connect(self.open_file)

        vlayout.addWidget(button_open)

        self.sldPosition = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.sldPosition.setMinimum(0)
        self.sldPosition.valueChanged.connect(self.mplPlayer.setPosition)

        self.mplPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.sldPosition.setValue)

        self.sldPosition.setEnabled(False)

        vlayout.addWidget(self.sldPosition)

        hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        self.button_play = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Play")
        self.button_play.clicked.connect(self.mplPlayer.play)
        self.button_play.setEnabled(False)

        hlayout.addWidget(self.button_play)

        self.button_pause = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Pause")
        self.button_pause.clicked.connect(self.mplPlayer.pause)
        self.button_pause.setEnabled(False)

        hlayout.addWidget(self.button_pause)

        self.button_stop = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Stop")
        self.button_stop.clicked.connect(self.mplPlayer.stop)
        self.button_stop.setEnabled(False)

        hlayout.addWidget(self.button_stop)

        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout)

        hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        label_volume = QtWidgets.QLabel("&Volume")

        hlayout.addWidget(label_volume)

        slider_volume = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        slider_volume.setRange(0, 100)
        slider_volume.setTickPosition(QtWidgets.QSlider.TicksAbove)
        slider_volume.setTickInterval(10)
        slider_volume.setValue(50)

        label_volume.setBuddy(slider_volume)

        button_mute = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Mute")
        button_mute.setCheckable(True)
        button_mute.toggled.connect(self.mplPlayer.setMuted)

        hlayout.addWidget(button_mute)
        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout)
        self.setLayout(vlayout)
        self.resize(300, 100)

    def open_file(self):
            file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileUrl(parent = self, 
                caption = "Choose musical file: ",
                filter = "Musical files (*.mp3 *.ac3)")
            self.mplPlayer.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(file[0]))

    def init_player(self, state):
        if state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.LoadedMedia:
            self.mplPlayer.stop()
            self.button_play.setEnabled(True)
            self.sldPosition.setEnabled(True)
            self.sldPosition.setMaximum(self.mplPlayer.duration())

        elif state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.NoMedia or state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.InvalidMedia:
            self.sldPosition.setValue(0)
            self.sldPosition.setEnabled(False)
            self.button_play.setEnabled(False)
            self.button_stop.setEnabled(False)
            self.button_pause.setEnabled(False)

    def set_player_state(self, state):
        if state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.StoppedState:
            self.sldPosition.setValue(0)
            self.button_pause.setEnabled(False)
            self.button_stop.setEnabled(False)

        elif state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.button_pause.setEnabled(True)
            self.button_stop.setEnabled(True)

        elif state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PausedState:
            self.button_pause.setEnabled(False)
            self.button_stop.setEnabled(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    window = AudioPlayer()
    window.setWindowTitle("Audio Player")
    window.show()

    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

замените

```
self.sldPosition.valueChanged.connect(self.mplPlayer.setPosition)
```

на

```
self.sldPosition.sliderMoved[int].connect(self.setPlayPosition)
```

и добавьте

```
def setPlayPosition(self, value): 
    self.mplPlayer.setPosition(value)
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtMultimedia

class AudioPlayer(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent, 
            flags = QtCore.Qt.Window 
            | QtCore.Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint
        )

        self.setWindowTitle("Audio Player")

        self.mplPlayer = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.mplPlayer.setVolume(50)                              
        self.mplPlayer.mediaStatusChanged.connect(self.init_player)
        self.mplPlayer.stateChanged.connect(self.set_player_state)

        vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        button_open = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Open file")
        button_open.clicked.connect(self.open_file)

        vlayout.addWidget(button_open)

        self.sldPosition = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.sldPosition.setMinimum(0)

#---        self.sldPosition.valueChanged.connect(self.mplPlayer.setPosition)   # ---
        self.sldPosition.sliderMoved[int].connect(self.setPlayPosition)         # +++ <<<-----<

        self.mplPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.sldPosition.setValue)
        self.sldPosition.setEnabled(False)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.sldPosition)

        hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        self.button_play = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Play")
        self.button_play.clicked.connect(self.mplPlayer.play)
        self.button_play.setEnabled(False)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.button_play)

        self.button_pause = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Pause")
        self.button_pause.clicked.connect(self.mplPlayer.pause)
        self.button_pause.setEnabled(False)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.button_pause)

        self.button_stop = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Stop")
        self.button_stop.clicked.connect(self.mplPlayer.stop)
        self.button_stop.setEnabled(False)

        hlayout.addWidget(self.button_stop)
        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout)
        hlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        label_volume = QtWidgets.QLabel("&Volume")
        hlayout.addWidget(label_volume)

        slider_volume = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        slider_volume.setRange(0, 100)
        slider_volume.setTickPosition(QtWidgets.QSlider.TicksAbove)
        slider_volume.setTickInterval(10)       
        slider_volume.setValue(50)
        label_volume.setBuddy(slider_volume)

        button_mute = QtWidgets.QPushButton("&Mute")
        button_mute.setCheckable(True)
        button_mute.toggled.connect(self.mplPlayer.setMuted)

        hlayout.addWidget(button_mute)
        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout)
        self.setLayout(vlayout)
        self.resize(300, 100)

    def open_file(self):
        file = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileUrl(parent = self, 
            caption = "Choose musical file: ",
            filter = "Musical files (*.mp3 *.ac3)")
        self.mplPlayer.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(file[0]))

    def init_player(self, state):
        if state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.LoadedMedia:
            self.mplPlayer.stop()
            self.button_play.setEnabled(True)
            self.sldPosition.setEnabled(True)
            self.sldPosition.setMaximum(self.mplPlayer.duration())

        elif state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.NoMedia or state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.InvalidMedia:
            self.sldPosition.setValue(0)
            self.sldPosition.setEnabled(False)
            self.button_play.setEnabled(False)
            self.button_stop.setEnabled(False)
            self.button_pause.setEnabled(False)

    def set_player_state(self, state):
        if state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.StoppedState:
            self.sldPosition.setValue(0)
            self.button_pause.setEnabled(False)
            self.button_stop.setEnabled(False)

        elif state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.button_pause.setEnabled(True)
            self.button_stop.setEnabled(True)

        elif state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PausedState:
            self.button_pause.setEnabled(False)
            self.button_stop.setEnabled(True)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def setPlayPosition(self, value):                                                 # +++
        self.mplPlayer.setPosition(value)                                             # +++


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = AudioPlayer()
    window.setWindowTitle("Audio Player")
    window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]